# Prefill PDF fillable form, save, then open for more form edits

Tags: c#, pdf

I've been able (using itextsharp) to insert data into fields on a pdf and save the pdf.  I can then open the new pdf and fill in any other fields and print it, but not save it again.

Is there any way to prefill some fields, save the pdf, then allow the user to enter more information in other fields and save the form again, keeping the fillable fields intact?

My project has to work with about 25-75 pdf forms at a time, so I don't want to try and keep them all in memory at the same time. And I would much prefer to not "print" a form to a pdf creator as those things tend to bloat the file sizes, as well as destroying the ability to come back later and fill in more fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a form is already "Reader Enabled", you have to set your PdfStamper to use "append mode" in order to maintain the Reader Enabled status.

There is no way to programmatically reader-enable a PDF outside of Expensive Adobe Server Software.  Tens of thousands of dollars at the low end.

If your PDFs aren't already Reader Enabled, then I'm afraid I don't understand your question.